# Array of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I try to create an array of vectors, I need really an ARRAY of VECTORS(not the vector of vectors), because position of the vector in array matters. The problem is, that I don't know the size of the array at the beginning I read it in from the file while calling a class constructor, so I think I should use "new" operator

```
std::vector<Vertex>* excess_vec ;
excess_vec = new std::vector<Vertex>[2*num_of_nodes];
```

where Vertex is a struct,
but filling an array of vectors in

```
for (int i = 0; i<vertices.size(); i++) {

        excess_vec[0].push_back(vertices[i]);
        excess_vec[3].push_back(vertices[i]);


}
```

such way, where vertices is a vector of Vertex
result this while debugging in Xcode

[image]

it looks like it is just a vector but not an array of vectors, I would expect something like this:

```
    [0]
      [0]
      [1]
      .
      .
      .

   [1]
   [2]
   [3]
     [0]
     [1]
     [2]
     .
     .
     .
```

So, I am a bit confused about this. Thanks in advance)

Comment: _"so I think I should use "new" operator"_ No. That's what `std::vector` is for.

Comment: But "new" is for array not for vector.

Comment: Given the fact that `std::vector` is just an encapsulated array, I don't see the point.

Comment: I don't understand why the compiler interprets it like this(image above)

Comment: @A.Kris You want `std::vector<std::vector<Vertex>> excess_vec(2*num_of_nodes) ;`

Comment: @A.Kris "compiler"? Do you mean "debugger"?

Comment: I just use breakpoints

Comment: I want to have`std::vector<std::vector<Vertex>> excess_vec(2*num_of_nodes) ;` as a private data of class, `num_of_points` is also I private data and I will read `num_of_points` from the file first in constructor, so I get an error declaring `std::vector<std::vector<Vertex>> excess_vec(2*num_of_nodes)`  this in private data

Comment: @A.Kris You know how to use member initializer lists in the constructor, do you?

Comment: Yes, I do. But the function that reads from file is the member of the class, so it would be much easier to use "new" for me in order to use member initializer lists in the constructor.

Comment: My guess (I don't have XCode): `excess_vec` is a pointer. The debugger doesn't know that it points to an array of objects, hence it only shows you one vector. And that is only one of the reasons you should rather use a vector of vectors.

Comment: @A.Kris You can also use `resize()` at any time to set the outer vectors size.

Comment: Thanks, `resize()` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an array of vectors while reading it's size from a file you have to do this:

```
int size;
in>>size;
vector<A>[size] vector_array;
```

I'm not sure what you want. If you want to read it's value from a file you can do this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<array.size();i++){
   //get data from file and convert it to the object you want
   vector_array[i] = generated_object;
}
```

If you want to copy vectors from an array to another vector array you can use this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<size_of_array_to_copy;i++){
    vector_array[i] = array_to_copy[i];
}
```

Yes, it will look like a tree, a vector of vectors looks like a tree too.
The fact that you're in a class constructor or that you will call one in the future doesn't change anything. It doesn't matter you're using a struct, structs and classes are similar.
You should just use vectors, they are just arrays with a dynamic size.